# Opening pdf files using Process.Start

Tags: c#, pdf, process.start

I am trying to open PDF files in Adobe reader using C#'s `Process.Start()`.

When I provide a path without white spaces it works fine, but paths and pdf files containing white spaces don't open.

This is my code:

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "AcroRd32";
string s = btn.Tag.ToString();
//btn.Tag Contains the full file path 
info.Arguments = s;
Process.Start(info);
```

If it is `C:\\Users\\Manish\\Documents\\ms_Essential_.NET_4.5.pdf` it works fine but if it is `F:\\Tutorials\\C#\\Foundational\\Microsoft Visual C# 2012 Step By Step V413HAV.pdf` Adobe Reader gives an error saying `there was an error in opening the document file can't be found`.

I have read through many questions related to this topic in SO but it won't work. As I can't figure out how to apply `@` prefix in my string `s`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to wrap the arguments around quotes:

```
info.Arguments = "\"" + s + "\"";
```

Comment: If it works, please accept this answer by ticking the green V.

Answer (score 9):

Just a little trick there is a default PDF reader set on the client: just use the file name as `FileName` if the process. Usually you don't care which program to use, so then this solution just works:

```
Process.Start(pdfFileName);
```

This doesn't need special quoting too, so it instantly fixes your problem.

Comment: I've already tried that before posting the question, but I needed it to be program specific, for future references, but, anyway, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Using the character @ before the string value should work:

```
var path = @"F:\Tutorials\C#\Foundational\Microsoft Visual C# 2012 Step By Step V413HAV.pdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enquote the path provided in the argument list. This will cause it to view the path as a single argument instead of multiple space separated arguments:

```
info.Arguments = "\"" + s + "\"";
```